# How to integrate paypal payment in asp .net mvc and receive payment status and info?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, paypal

This question has been bugging me for a long time. 
I have tried everything there is in Paypal docs (braintree, paypal api) except buttons who can't help me out since I need to get payment confirmation from paypal and add credit to users account.

Main problem is I am not native English speaker and I am junior developer, and I need some kind of tutorial that goes step-by-step and explains it fundamentally.
I set-up everything regarding test accounts and so on, but actual payment (via sandbox) and receiving payment info has been hell for me.

If someone can help me out with advice I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you might want to take a look at this PayPal SDK on Github

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK

> The PayPal .NET SDK makes it easy to add PayPal support to your .NET
>   web application and is built on PayPal's REST APIs.

Comment: Thank you mate, sorry I didn't have points before to upvote your comment. I did a wast research and made it to the solution :D

Comment: Please take note that the PayPal NET SDK is deprecated.

Comment: @Alde - but you can reach the current version via a link at top there.

Comment: I it safe to use in website?